# iOS How to force resize UINavigationBar's title label in width

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I'm looking for a way to force resize the navigation bar's title label to present whole title string ("Title" instead of "Tit..."). Anyone have an idea how to do it? The reason I want to do it, is that I have a double navigation bar (2x height) with buttons in the upper half and title below them. The problem is, title label gets shrinked in width to prevent it from overlapping with buttons as if they were on the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I've found the solution, so I'm posting it in case someone encounters the same problem.

You have to overwrite your navigations bar's `layoutSubviews` method like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect currentFrame = self.topItem.titleView.frame;
    self.topItem.titleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 
                                              currentFrame.origin.y,
                                              [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,
                                              currentFrame.size.height);
}
```

It will make your title label take full screen width, but you can change the values of frame size to suit your needs.